# Single and double underscore difference in declaring @synthesize

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In a recent Xcode 4.3 project template, some `@synthesze` are declared as:

```
@synthesize window = _window;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize managedObjectModel = __managedObjectModel;
@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator = __persistentStoreCoordinator;
@synthesize navigationController = _navigationController;
```

Some come with a double underscore (`__`) as prefix. Why?

Anything to do with `readonly` attribute?

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (readonly, strong, nonatomic) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They probably shouldn't use a double underscore, if they're intended for use in your own program.  I expect it's just an oversight on the part of whoever wrote that template example.  In practice, it's unlikely that they'll cause any problems.

The C standard reserves all identifiers starting with a double underscore for the implementation's own use.  Since Objective-C is a superset of C, you shouldn't be using those identifiers in Objective-C programs either.  From the C spec, section **7.1.3 Reserved identifiers**:

> All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.

Answer (score 1):

Probably in this case. In general, apple tends to use _ prefixed names to refer to the external copy of a variable (such as when passed as a function, or the direct ref as opposed to the property). Whoever wrote that code probably thought they were being clever by adding an extra _ for read-only, but this is generally bad practice since C reserves the __ for specifying compiler directives.

I've never seen a C compiler complain about __ vars, and LLVM doesn't seem to mind, but it probably isn't good practice.